# How do I input data and simultaneously remove empty elements?

Tags: c#, io

This code works:

```
 var Input = File.ReadAllLines(FilePath).Select(line => line.Split(' ')).ToArray();
```

This code doesn't work:

```
var Input = File.ReadAllLines(FilePath).Select(line => line.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)).ToArray();
```

I get the error: "cannot convert from 'System.StringSplitOptions' to 'char'.
I am trying to remove empty elements with this addition.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call `Split` it like:

```
 line.Split(new []{' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Because `StringSplitOptins` can be passed with an array of characters or an array of string elements.

See: [`String.Split Method (Char[], StringSplitOptions)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

So your statement should be:

```
var Input = File.ReadAllLines(FilePath)
                .Select(line => line.Split(new []{' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                .ToArray();
```

Comment: Can you help me understand this fine distinction?  It seems that a new array[] is being created in your code, whereas in my code no new array[] was created?

Comment: @phan, the `string.Split` overload which accepts `StringSplitOptions` require an array of characters or strings, since you are only passing a single element, you need to pass it through array, thus `new []`, you can also use: `line.Split(new char[]{' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` , Its same.